# SwingWorker Process() warning

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I tried to write a simple test program using Swing, all I want to do is load a text file and display the path of the chosen text file in a text area. I keep getting a warning on the process method "never used locally" and it is not appending any text to the textbox. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, I hope someone can help me.

code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;



public class MyPanel3 extends JPanel{ 

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea jcomp;
    private JButton btn;
    private String testfile;

    public MyPanel3() {


        //construct components
        jcomp = new JTextArea (1, 1);
        jcomp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLACK)); 
        btn = new JButton ("open");

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension (944, 575));
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout (this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);


        //add main components
        add (jcomp);
        add (btn);


        new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){


            protected Void doInBackground(){

                //do processes...       
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                        final JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
                        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt","txt");
                        chooseFile.setFileFilter(filter);
                        chooseFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                        chooseFile.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

                        if(ae.getSource().equals(btn))  
                        {  
                            System.out.println("do in background running");

                            int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(MyPanel3.this);

                            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                            {                                                                   
                                File[] files = chooseFile.getSelectedFiles();


                                 testfile = files[0].getPath();

                                 publish(testfile);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                return null;
            }


            protected void process(String s) {
                        jcomp.append(s);

            }


        protected void done() {

            try 
            {
                //System.out.println("The operation was completed");
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        }.execute();    
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ("MyTest");
        frame.getContentPane();     
        frame.add(new MyPanel3());      
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible (true);               
    }
}
```

warning reads:

> The method process(String) from the type new
>   SwingWorker(){} is never used locally

EDIT:
with help from MadProgrammer, program is now working (selecting 3 files and printing the paths as strings in the text box)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class MyPanel4 extends JPanel {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea jcomp;
    private JButton btn;


    public MyPanel4() {
        //construct components
        jcomp = new JTextArea(1, 1);
        jcomp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLACK));
        btn = new JButton("open");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                final JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt");
                chooseFile.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooseFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                chooseFile.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

                int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(MyPanel4.this);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    final File[] files = chooseFile.getSelectedFiles();


                    new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {

                        private String testfile1 = files[0].getPath();
                        private String testfile2 = files[1].getPath();
                        private String testfile3 = files[2].getPath();



                        protected Void doInBackground() {

                            List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();

                            b.add(testfile1);
                            b.add(testfile2);
                            b.add(testfile3);   

                            publish(b.get(0));
                            publish(b.get(1));
                            publish(b.get(2));

                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {

                            for (String pathname : chunks) 
                            {
                                jcomp.append(pathname + "\n");
                            }
                        }

                        protected void done() {
                            try 
                            {
                                System.out.println("Opration Completed");

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(944, 575));
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);

        //add main components
        add(jcomp);
        add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTest");
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.add(new MyPanel4());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put your action listener in side the doInBackGround, instead, swap them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SwingWorker` should be created inside the buttons `actionPerformed` method, so that when you click the button, it will run the `SwingWorker`

You should, also, make sure that all interactions with user interface are fine from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. This means you should ask the user to select the file fro within the context of the `actionPerformed` method and pass the result to the `SwingWorked`

**Updated**

Two additional things...

1. You're not actually reading the file, but simply passing the name of the file to the `publish` method
2. `SwingWorker` defines `process` as `protected void process(List<V> chunks)` but you've defined it as `protected void process(String s)`...mean that you are actually not overriding the `SwingWorker`'s `process` method, but creating your own...

Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212654/displaying-whatever-has-been-read-from-a-file-in-a-gui/13212766#13212766) to see how you might be able to use a `SwingWorker` to read a file...

And, update your `process` to have the corrected method signature...

```
@Override
protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
    for (String line : chunks) {
        output.append(line);
    }
}
```

Remember, you should, as much as possible, use the `@Override` annotation when you think you are overriding a method, the compiler will tell you when you are mistaken, saving you a lot of head scratching...

Comment: yes tried it but still no text, could it be that i'm missing some logic with the process/publish method? I read the oracle documentation on SwingWorker and found it very confusing to comprehend from the example there

Comment: You're not actually reading the file, but simply passing the name of the file (via the `publish` method).  Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212654/displaying-whatever-has-been-read-from-a-file-in-a-gui/13212766#13212766)

Comment: thanks for that example but i'm nearly sure there is a problem with my compiler now..  when I try to use a List<String> parameter in the swingworker thread it displays an error "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
  <String>"  tried compiling with both JRE1.6 and 1.7 and i'm still getting this error?!

Comment: oh right.. I see thanks,, I'll leave it for now and come back to it tomorrow, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class MyPanel3 extends JPanel {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextArea jcomp;
    private JButton btn;
    private String testfile;

    public MyPanel3() {
        //construct components
        jcomp = new JTextArea(1, 1);
        jcomp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLACK));
        btn = new JButton("open");

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                final JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".txt", "txt");
                chooseFile.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooseFile.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                chooseFile.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

                int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(MyPanel3.this);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File[] files = chooseFile.getSelectedFiles();

                    testfile = files[0].getPath();

                    new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
                        protected Void doInBackground() {
                            publish(testfile);
                            return null;
                        }

                        protected void process(String s) {
                            jcomp.append(s);
                        }

                        protected void done() {
                            try {
                                //System.out.println("The operation was completed");
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }.execute();
                }
            }
        });

        //adjust size and set layout
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(944, 575));
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);

        //add main components
        add(jcomp);
        add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTest");
        frame.getContentPane();
        frame.add(new MyPanel3());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

You are running worker when you are creating panel. But you should run it when button is clicked.

Comment: yes I see what you mean although I'm still getting the warning when I try this code and it still doesn't append the text :/